# Node.js Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

I'm trying to get some code to listen to an API, and return results.
Depending on what API returns, certain functions invoke.

It listens to the API, and can stream data in the console log, aswell as invoke the functions passing proper parameters.
**BUT**
It will only work for maybe 2 to 15 minutes before returning:

"Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

After a ton of google searches I found that my problem was that I need to somehow define my variables value upon declaration, even though the variable doesn't have a value until the API returns data for it. Though I have no idea how to do that, and the examples I've seen did not work for my code.

```
async function main () {
await smoke.api.streamOperations('head', function(err, result){
    var type = result[0] //<--- This is the line that will return a typeError
    var data = result[1]
//More stuff too happen//
}
```

I expect the result to be the first value of the returned string from API.
It succeeds, if there is no typeError. (It will return with values such as comment, vote, custom_json)
TypeError happens EVERY time, it's just a matter of how long before it does.

The exact error I'm getting is:

`Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

How do I avoid this???

**UPDATE**

I have removed the async and await expressions
- It functions smoother, but still runs into the same typeError

```
function main () {
smoke.api.streamOperations('head', function(err, result){
  //var type = 0
    var type = result[0]
    var data = result[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for async / await is wrong, when you use async / await, a callback function is not required. So the value result in the callback is `undefined`. Try using it as follows:

```
async function main () {
    var result = await smoke.api.streamOperations('head');
    var type = result[0]; //<--- This is the line that will return a typeError
    var data = result[1];
    //More stuff too happen//
}
```

Comment: Will it returns a promise. Then only we can actually use async and await. He didn't mention there it returns promise.

Comment: @PrinceDevadoss Then I don't think async await can be used, normal callback will have to be used by removing async and await keywords.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I gave it a shot, and instead of giving me a typeError in console and stopping the script. It called an error handler I had written below:

```
if (typeof type === 'undefined') {
    console.log(result)
    console.log('Caught undefined promise')
  }
```

The script continued to run after catching the error - which was a good step. But it broke the rest of the API listening code. instead of returning "vote" or "comment" etc as expected.. It returned [function]

Comment: @freshcoder Can you post the rest of your code? It's a bit difficult to understand the exact problem without the ability to run the code.

Comment: @freshcoder Can you console `result` and see what is the value? Maybe the request is not in a proper format.

Comment: Console Log gives this(or similar) on success ----Parsed API Data:
[ 'comment',
  { parent_author: 'luismy',
    parent_permlink: 'my-little-plants-are-growing-very-well-weedreport',
    author: 'maxstrell',
    permlink:
     're-luismy-my-little-plants-are-growing-very-well-weedreport-20190607t083720653z',
    title: ----------ETC.......---------------
Console Log produces this on error--------------------------------->Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at /home/runner/index.js:40:19
--------ETC......Although I'm lucky to get 2 minutes runtime